# Serving mkdocs site with nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, mkdocs

could anyone point in the right direction on how to serve an mkdocs site on centos using nginx? Or maybe there is a better way of doing it?

Any info is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's the same as hosting a static website with NGINX, because mkdocs generated site is just static files. Point `root` of NGINX to where your `index.html` is, and you're done...

Comment: Why you don't use GitHub pages as the simplest option for hosting static site?

Comment: @ZoranPandovski It is running on a remote access VPN server

Comment: @DanilaVershinin could you give an example configuration for nginx.conf pointing to sites folder for mkdocs where the index.html resides? I keep getting 403 Forbidden. nginx/1.20.1 when I try to open it in the browser

Comment: I resolved the issue, it was actually a problem with user permissions, hence the 403 Forbidden error message. Thanks